# Get all strings between triple Pipes, e.g. |||Hello|||, from a text

Tags: c#, regex, match

I wanted to get all strings, that are surrounded by triple pipes (like `|||Hello|||`) from a text and found this regex in C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@".*?\|\|\|(\w+)\|\|\|"); // searches strings, which are surrounded by three pipes >>> |||string|||
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(strContent))
{
    lstReturn.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

It works as it should with small strings, but not on a large text (freezes without response).

Can you please tell me how I can make this query faster or suggest an alternative?

Comment: Why do you use `.*?` at the start? Use just `\|\|\|(\w+)\|\|\|`.

Comment: Because of my lack of knowledge of regex. it solved it, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*?` at the start of your pattern makes matching slower since the engine needs to perform more checks once the subsequent subpatterns fail. Once there is no `|` the `.*?` is "expanded", or "backtracked", and the non-`|` char is matched with `.*?`. With very long strings, this leads to catastrophic backtracking.

The second pattern also allows for internal optimization since the regex engine knows the match will start with a `|` hardcoded char.

You need to remove `.*?` since you do not need the part before `|||word|||`.

You can compare [`.*?\|\|\|(\w+)\|\|\|`](https://regex101.com/r/D0NgRo/1/debugger) and [`\|\|\|(\w+)\|\|\|`](https://regex101.com/r/D0NgRo/2/debugger) matching steps:

First one:

[image]

Second one:

[image]

You can see that "red arrows" denoting backtracking fire more often in the first image.